# Is there any way to create triggers owned by SYS or what will be the solution for this

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I am having an issue to create **Trigger** I am attaching a photo of my cmd bellow

[image]

This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_salary_changes
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON customers 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0)
DECLARE
    sal_diff number;
BEGIN
    sal_diff := :NEW.salary - :OLD.salary;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary ' || :OLD.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary ' || :NEW.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference ' || :sal_diff);
END;
/
```

**ERROR**

> ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS

what will be the possible solution for this or what will I do now please give me some suggestion

Comment: Surely the error message is self-explanatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your customer table created by SYS user.

Create an user using sys like 'MY_USER' connect with it then create your customer table with MY_USER. And try create your trigger. Drop `sys.customer` table.

> This account can perform all administrative functions. All base
>   (underlying) tables and views for the database data dictionary are
>   stored in the SYS schema. These base tables and views are critical for
>   the operation of Oracle Database. To maintain the integrity of the
>   data dictionary, tables in the SYS schema are manipulated only by the
>   database. They should never be modified by any user or database
>   administrator. You must not create any tables in the SYS schema.

According: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked for me